# Server 2012 Remote Desktop User Profile Disks and User Profiles on Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, user-profile

I have a new MS Server 2012 as a Terminal Server to deal with Remote Desktop connections to my small business.
Unlike my previous MS Server 2003 it doesn't seem to just work with the Roaming User Profiles from my Main Active Directory Domain Server (Server 2008).

Is it possible to use point "User Profile Disks" for the new Remote Desktop setup at the share that contains the standard User Profiles on the main Server 2008 and it all work as expected, or will this break things when the users come back into the office and log onto the domain with their Windows XP client PCs

Does anyone know of a way to make the Remote Desktops in Server 2012 use the default profiles from a 2008 Server?

Cheers
phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was quite a bit of changes to the folder structure in profiles when moving from a 2003 (or earlier) Terminal server to 2008 (and later). Even with the profile directory pointed to the same location 2008 will create a new v2 profile folder to account for the differences in folder structure.

Microsoft does have a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;947025) on 2 methods to migrating the profiles between the two versions. Basically, it comes down to using USMT to migrate the profiles as a whole, or moving to redirected folders with roaming profiles to point the main user folders to a common source. Redirected folders will migrate the data but not user settings.